# Only Group Owner can read group members?

Tags: permissions, groups, membership

In Group Setting there is the following option: Who can view the membership of the group? a) Group Members b)Everyone

I have the requirements that only the owner should see the Group members. Basically, I have a group "Suppliers" and there members are not allowed to read the goup membership. How can I implement this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't out of the box.

My suggestion would be to create an AD Security group comprised of the users in question. Then use this AD group in your SharePoint group for permissions, leaving the membership setting to Group Members.

They will only see the AD group listed and no individual users.

Comment: Hello Eric, 
Thanks for the answer. I am sure that it could be usefull for others, but in my case it is not working. We are using OpenID Providers, therefore users are added to sharepoint groups just with an e-mail address. 
Kind regards